# R glm - How to predict the same coefficient from two different dataset with the same data format and value

Tags: r, reference, prediction, glm, predict

So let me explain my goal.

(1) I have an existing glm with P input variables which one of them is named 'X'.

(2) I have multiple datasets from different systems that each contains the 'X' input variable, but with a different names. Once I extract the dataset from the system, I am able to know the name of the variable that corresponds to 'X'.

(3) I want to use the `predict(*)` R function for each dataset. I wonder if there is a way to do so without renaming to 'X' the input variable such as adding a reference column name that the `predict` function can read instead of the raw column name. I guess if there is no way to do it, I will need to create a temporary dataset with the input variable renamed 'X', because I do not want to modify the columns name in the original dataset.

(4 Extra) I want to solve the same problem, but with multiple glm with the same input variable 'X' with different names.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but it sounds as though you want to be able to use `predict.glm` where the `newdata` argument contains an independent variable that is named differently to the equivalent independent variable in the data frame that was used to create the `glm`. However, you don't want to have to rename the column in the new data frame.

One way to do this is create a wrapper for `predict` that takes the names of the variable to be substituted in the new data frame, as well as the variable in the model it represents. Lets call it `predict2`:

```r
predict2 <- function(model, newdata, oldvar, newvar, ...)
{
  if(!missing(oldvar) & !missing(newvar))
  {
    oldname <- deparse(substitute(oldvar))
    names(newdata)[which(names(newdata) == deparse(substitute(newvar)))] <- oldname
  }
  predict.glm(model, newdata = newdata, ...)
}
```

Now let's see how this would work. You haven't given us a reproducible example, but here's a very simple one. It's just a logistic regression on a three-level factor variable called `X`:

```r
set.seed(69)
df1 <- data.frame(outcome = rbinom(15, 1, rep(c(.1, .5, .9), each = 5)),
                  X = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5))

mod <- glm(outcome ~ X, df1, family = binomial)

predict(mod)
#>           1           2           3           4           5           6 
#> -19.5660685 -19.5660685 -19.5660685 -19.5660685 -19.5660685  -0.4054651 
#>           7           8           9          10          11          12 
#>  -0.4054651  -0.4054651  -0.4054651  -0.4054651   1.3862944   1.3862944 
#>          13          14          15 
#>   1.3862944   1.3862944   1.3862944
```

Now if we create a new data frame where the factor variable is called `Y`, which for illustration only contains B's, we have a problem when we try to use our model:

```
df2 <- data.frame(outcome = rbinom(15, 1, .5), Y = rep('B', 15))

predict(mod, newdata = df2)
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'X' not found
```

However, with our new function `predict2`, we just tell it to use `Y` in place of `X`, and we should get our result (which, since they are all B's should all be -0.4054651:

```r
predict2(mod, newdata = df2, oldvar = X, newvar = Y)
#>          1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
#> -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 
#>          8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
#> -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 -0.4054651 
#>         15 
#> -0.4054651
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>